# Virtualbox and ssh connection

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I'm trying to configure virtualbox to allow access from outside (including the host) to ssh server running on guest system (Linux Mint). I know that i can use NAT (default setting) with port forwarding. If i'm right that in the port forwarding settings under the "host IP" field i should set my host IP, eg. 192.168.0.11 if this is the IP address of my Windows host?

Answer (score 1):

You can leave Host IP blank. Example:

**Name:** SSH

**Protocol:** TCP

**Host Port:** 2222

**Guest Port:** 22

After, you can connect with PuTTY for example with IP Address and port 2222.

Comment: where do you put these settings

Comment: @yoyo_fun Go to your Virtual Machine Settings->Network->Advanced->Port Forwarding, there you can click + sign on the right and add a rule.